# SQL (Oracle) - Selecting rows containing a max() using 'having'

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I have the following tables for a university database:

```
takes(ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade)
section(course_id, sec_id, semester, year)
```

I need to determine which sections had the maximum number of students enrolled in Fall semester of 2009.

I have tried variations of the following query:

```
with sec_enrollment as(
    select course_id, sec_id, count(ID) as enrollment
    from section natural join takes
    where semester = 'Fall' and year = 2009
    group by course_id, sec_id)
select course_id, sec_id, enrollment
from sec_enrollment
group by course_id, sec_id, enrollment
having enrollment = max(enrollment)
```

The above query returns all sections from Fall 2009 instead of just the sections with max enrollment.  It seems that my 'having' clause is being ignored.

If I use the query:

```
with sec_enrollment as(
    select course_id, sec_id, count(ID) as enrollment
    from section natural join takes
    where semester = 'Fall' and year = 2009
    group by course_id, sec_id)
select max(enrollment)
from sec_enrollment
```

I can get the desired value for the maximum enrollment.  I just can't figure out how to get the desired value along with course_id and sec_id of sections that contain that maximum.  I'm thinking that the 'group by' clause is screwing things up, but I can't configure it any other way without drawing an error (ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression).  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it using one more `cte`.

```
with sec_enrollment as (
select course_id, sec_id, count(ID) as enrollment
from section natural join takes
where semester = 'Fall' and year = 2009
group by course_id, sec_id)
, max_enrollment as (
select max(enrollment) as maxenrollment from sec_enrollment)
select course_id, sec_id 
from sec_enrollment s 
join max_enrollment m on s.enrollment = m.maxenrollment
```

Answer (score 0):

Order the results in descending order by the enrollment count and then limit the results to 1 record.

```
with sec_enrollment as(
    select course_id, sec_id, count(ID) as enrollment
    from section natural join takes
    where semester = 'Fall' and year = 2009
    group by course_id, sec_id)
select course_id, sec_id, enrollment
    from sec_enrollment
    where ROWNUM = 1
    order by enrollment DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write the query simpler as:

```
 select course_id, sec_id, enrollment
 from (
      select s.course_id, s.sec_id, count(t.ID) as enrollment
      from section s join takes t
      where s.semester = 'Fall' and s.year = 2009
      group by s.course_id, s.sec_id
      order by count(t.ID)
 ) 
 where rownuw <= 1
```

When you have to find the item who has the max value, you don't need to find the max value and later find the item who has that value. There are two operations when you could just find the max and the item in the same operation, with a sort operation.